# Get the data from databases for each primaryKey in parallel

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I have list of primary keys ex: `empids`, I want to get the employee information for each `emplid` from the database.  Or rather, *I want to get the data from different databases based on different types of `empids` using **multiple threads**.*

Currently I'm fetching first employee information and save it into Java bean and fetch second employee and saved it into bean so on.  Finally adding all these beans into `ArrayList`, but now I want to get data from databases in parallel. Means at a time I want to get the employee information for each employee and save it into bean.

Basically I'm looking parallel processing rather than sequentially to improve the performance.

Comment: Use a query that results more than one `employees` rows (based on your requirement). Iterate through `ResultSet`, pack the rows into bean/pojo/vo, add them to a `List` created outside the loop. When out of loop, return the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're looking for parallelism in this case. You really are looking for a single query that will return all employees whose id is in the collection of Ids that you have. One database connection, one thread, one query, and a result set.

If you are using hibernate, this is super easy with Hibernate Criteria where you can use a Restrictions.IN on the employeeId and pass it the collection of ids. The query underneath will be something like `select a, b, c, ..., n from Employee where employee_id in (1,2,3,4...,m)`

If you are using straight JDBC, you can achieve the same in your native query, you will need to change the ResultSet parsing because you will now expect a collection back.

Comment: @john  That should have been an edit to your question (or preferably as part of the *original* question).  I've added it in, so you can delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callable task for fetching the employee information and return the `ArrayList` from that callable (thread).

You can then submit the tasks using a Executor and get the handle of the futures to loop back on results.

```
//sudo code for 
Future<Arraylist<Employee>> fut = executor.submit(new EmployeeInfoTask(empIds));
//EmployeeInfoTask is a callable

for(Arraylist<Employee> result : fut){
    //print result;
}
```

See [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

EDIT - for java 1.4

In this case you can still make the database calls in different threads but you will need to make each thread write to a shared Employee collection. Don't forget to synchronize the access to this collection.

Also you will need to join() on all the threads which you have spawned so that you know when all the threads are done..

Comment: but im using jdk1.4 and java.util.concurrent is not available in jdk1.4